# Reinstalling Vim

Tags: vim, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

I'm trying to reinstall vim in ubuntu 11.10, but am having trouble. From the software center I click on install, and I get the error message: "Failed to download package files. Check your internet connection". My internet connection is fine.

Then, I click on OK, and this message comes up: "Requires Installation of untrusted packages." I click on OK (the only option), and the installation ceases. Anyone know how I resolve this problem?

Comment: Why would you need to reinstall VIM? I've never heard of it being broken.

Comment: This is a better question for http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 3):

Try from command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim gvim
```

Comment: This seems to have worked (it completed with no errors). But there is no formatting of the text (it's all white on a dark background). I can't find the vim folder in /usr/share/ where it used to be. Do you know where I can find this folder?

Comment: @user1024973: Do you have a second vim installation on your system? what is the output of running `which gvim`?

Answer (score 0):

Before running the commands from @DiogoDoreto 's post, run

```
sudo apt-get purge vim gvim
```

Then run update and install.
Purge will clear out all of the old configuration files and will usually fix the problem.

Comment: That didn't work for me. The command completes just fine but there is no change. Vim is still in /usr/share/vim as before