# How to reinstall vim?

Tags: vim

I have problems with my vim in Ubuntu 11.10, when I press 'i' or 'v' vim doesn't show anything like 'INSERT MODE' or 'VISUAL MODE', when I try to delete with backspace, vim only move the cursor to the left. I tried reinstalling with this [Reinstalling Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234099/reinstalling-vim) but got the same result, also I don't have ~/.vim directory.

It works fine whith **:set nocp**, why ?

Answer (score 10):

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vim
```

that will give you the version 7.2.330 or so

You can add `:set nocp` in your `~/.vimrc`

Comment: I got the same result :(

Comment: did you try: apt-get upgrade, then install vim again?

Comment: weird, did you remove any vim config? no cap locks?

Comment: When I do :set nocp it works fine, where can I set this for default?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the vim installed on ubuntu system(1 CD ubuntu setup) is minimal vim .... try to upgrade it to the full version.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vim
```

Answer (score 2):

Check `/etc/vim/` and see what's there.

`apt-get purge vim` before re-installing it might help too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already tried reinstalling, try the following: remove `/etc/vimrc` and `$HOME/.vimrc` and see if the problem persists. It might be that something changed in your configuration that's giving you troubles